# How can I prevent a report in SSRS from splitting string data containing commas into multiple columns?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using Visual Studios to edit a report.  The field in question is pulling data from a database column containing user-entered comments.  For example, a value could be:

"User attempted banging head on keyboard, pulling hair out, and crying in the corner"

The report however shows only "User attempted banging head on keyboard" while moving "pulling hair out" and "crying in the corner" to new columns.

I'm new to SSRS and apparently do not know enough SSRS terminology to ask the internets properly but I am familiar enough with SQL and SSIS to understand functions and expressions.  I just can not seem to find the right tools in SSRS to display the string data correctly.

For the record, I am only editing a pre-existing report built by someone else so I have no control over the data being used or the overall design of the report.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see any reason why a field value would split into multiple columns. This is definitely not normal. What kind of SSRS control are you rendering this on to? In order for there to be additional columns appearing dynamically it must be a Matrix?

Comment: First thing to do is look at the dataset query and see what that is doing, as Nick said this is not normal behaviour but maybe the data is being extracted from a CSV? Anyway, look at the dataset query and if required, EDIT your question and show the dataset query and report design.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I found a work-around.  I will still play with an old copy and try to figure out the actual answer though.  Not a matrix (to the best of my knowledge).  The string was approximately 800 characters but was cut off about 50 characters in (not at a comma).  The next column would pick up the string after the first comma and continue until the 2nd comma was found, which would cause a jump to the next column where it would continue.  The dataset column was defined as varchar(1500).  Redefining the column to varchar(MAX) seems to correct or circumvent the issue.